# JwtStrategy class is not working for cognito access token

Tags: jwt, nestjs, amazon-cognito, passport.js, passport-jwt

I'm trying to validate the user access tokens by running them through my `JwtStrategy` class in nestjs. Besides my approach I've tried quite a few of the tutorial ones with no luck. I keep getting a 401 even when using auth0. My `LocalStrategy` works fine and outputs the accesstoken as well as other expected information.

Here is my JwtStrategy class:

```
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Strategy, ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { passportJwtSecret } from 'jwks-rsa';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 3,
        jwksUri: `https://cognito-idp.${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}/.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: process.env.AWS_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      issuer: `https://cognito-idp.${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}`,
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  validate(payload: any) {
    if (!payload) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return payload;
  }
}
```

Here is my AuthModule:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';
import { LocalStrategy } from './local.strategy';
import { PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Module({
  imports: [PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' })],
  providers: [JwtStrategy, LocalStrategy],
  exports: [],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

This is the endpoint I'm trying to hit:

```
import { Controller, Get, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  getHello(): string {
    return this.appService.getHello();
  }
}
```

This is my jwt auth guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {}
```

- Removing the `@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))` line in the intended endpoint yields the expected result
- I tried using tokens/implementations from both cognito and auth0 so I don't believe this is an idp issue
- I verified that this `https://cognito-idp.${process.env.AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${process.env.AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID}/.well-known/jwks.json`, indeed produced the correct JSON result
- I have double and triple checked the env variables used in the JwtStrategy class
- The access token is a valid jwt token